# enable caching of images only in specific folder

Tags: .htaccess

I have the below htacess code and am wondering how i can specify it to only apply to a specific folder. in this case, only all image files in: /public_html/img/icons/

```
<filesMatch ".(png)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
</filesMatch>
```

Comment: FilesMatch doesn't work with any paths, file names only. You could put this into a .htaccess placed in the /public_html/img/icons/ folder. Or you could replace FilesMatch with an `IF` (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#examples) based on the `REQUEST_URI` environment variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set an environment variable (using `SetEnvIf`) when the URL requested matches the specific folder and image type(s). Set the `Header` conditionally based on this env var (using the `env=` argument of the `Header` directive).

For example:

```
# Cache images in the "/img/icons" subdirectory
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/img/icons/.+\.(png|jpg|gif)$" ENABLE_CACHE
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public" env=ENABLE_CACHE
```

This method allows you to keep all the directives in the single `.htaccess` file in the document root. It also works on all versions of Apache (unlike `<If>` expressions that require Apache 2.4).

However, this may also be dependent on other directives you have in the `.htaccess` file. If, for instance, you are on Apache (as opposed to LiteSpeed) and rewriting the URL with mod_rewrite (a front-controller pattern perhaps) then you may need to test for `REDIRECT_ENABLE_CACHE` in the `Header` directive instead. (Or change your existing directives to prevent a loop of the rewrite engine, that results in the env var being prefixed with `REDIRECT_`.)